# HTML POST a label

Tags: html, post

I dont know the correct term for this "Label" that im talking about - its not within label tags, its simply

```
<td width="300"> text </td>
```

I want to be able to "POST" this to a php script. I know how to post, but not from the above label/text 
The reason i want to do this is because i had a text box that was auto-filled from session Variables. 
But i had used the "disabled" feature within HTML, but that then made the stuff being "posted" to my php script be treated as empty, by removing the "disabled" line, it works but i need it so the text is not editable by the user.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cant post text like that, but you can make an input field hidden.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield" value="text" />
```

You can also make an input field read only by applying the read only attribute, instead of using disabled.

```
<input type="text" name="rofield" value="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: is there anyway of doing that, but not actually hiding the text, so that the user can still see it? Would make the website look a whole lot better if they could see what information of theirs is being used.